# If $p, q$ and $r$ are distinct roots of $x^3-x^2+x-2=0$, find the value of $p^3+q^3+r^3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

**If $p, q$ and $r$ are distinct roots of $x^3-x^2+x-2=0$, find the value of $p^3+q^3+r^3$.**

Here's what I have got,

> By Vieta's rule
>
> $p+q+r=1\text{.               ...........}(1)$
>
> $pq+qr+pr=1\text{.               ...........}(2)$
>
> $pqr=2\text{.               ...........}(3)$
>
> Squaring $(1)$,
>
> $p^2+q^2+r^2+2(pq+qr+pr)=1\text{.               ...........}(4)$
>
> From $(2)$,
>
> $p^2+q^2+r^2=-1\text{.               ...........}(5)$
>
> Putting the roots and adding these equations,
>
> $p^3-p^2+p-2=0$
>
> $q^3-q^2+q-2=0$
>
> $r^3-r^2+r-2=0$
>
> We get,
>
> $(p^3+q^3+r^3)-(p^2+q^2+r^2)+(p+q+r)-6=0$
>
> Putting the values,
>
> $(p^3+q^3+r^3)-(-1)+1-6=0$
>
> $(p^3+q^3+r^3)=4$

**Am I doing something wrong in my solution?**

Because the answer given is -5.

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: The answer givenn in the book may be wrong because even I got 4. I believe you're referring to Pathfinder textbook. Even I use that book.

Comment: @SujalMotagi You're preparing for Olympiads?

Comment: Yes I am preparing for PRMO. I'm moving from 8th to 9th standard. This will be the first time I am writing PRMO.

Comment: I thought I found out about Olympiads too late and I won't be able to clear them when I found out about them. Anyways, I have Challenge and Thrill of Pre College Mathematics. And I have pdf's of many math textbooks. I watch the prmo 2020 course by unacademy on YouTube. What about you?

Comment: That's actually better. Because I found out about Olympiads recently and I became obsessed with them, so I'm not able to enjoy the problems. It's better to solve the problems for fun than to clear the exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the strict $p^3+q^3+r^3-3pqr=(p+q+r)(p^2+q^2+r^2-pq-qr-rp)$. It's easy to compute $p^2+q^2+r^2$ and use Viete's rule.

Comment: Thanks, but Applying this method also gives 4. The answer given in the book is -5 which doesn't really match my answer. I think it maybe a typographical error.

Comment: Your answer is correct. It's 4 not -5

Answer (score 2):

$$p³+q³+r³ = (p+q+r)³-3(p+q)(q+r)(r+p)$$
$$ = (1)³- 3(1-r)(1-p)(1-q)$$
$$ = 1-3(1-1+1-2) =4$$
Here, 1-1+1-2= the sum of coefficients of the given equation

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^3-2)^3=(x^2-x)^3$$

$$(x^3)^3-8-3(x^3)^22+3(x^3)2^2=(x^3)^2-(x^3)-3x^2\cdot x(x^3-2)$$

Replace $x^3=y$ to find

$$y^3-8-3y^2\cdot2+3y\cdot2^2=y^2-y-3y(y-2)$$

$$\iff y^3-y^2(6+1-3)+\cdots=0$$ whose roots are $ p^3,q^3,r^3$

$$\implies p^3+q^3+r^3=\dfrac{6+1-3}1$$