# Let $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ be the roots of the equation $x^2+px+q=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, quadratics

> Let $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ be the roots of the equation
>    $x^2+px+q=0$. Find $p$ and $q$ if it is known that $x_1+1$ and $x_2+1$
>    are the roots of the equation $x^2-p^2x+pq=0$.

The roots of $x^2+px+q=0$ satisfy $$x_1+x_2=-\dfrac{b}{a}=-p,x_1x_2=\dfrac{c}{a}=q.$$ Also the roots of $x^2-p^2x+pq=0$ satisfy $$x_1+x_2=x_1+1+x_2+1=x_1+x_2+2=-\dfrac{b}{a}=p^2,x_1x_2=(x_1+1)(x_2+1)=\dfrac{c}{a}=pq.$$ Is it confusing I am using $x_1$ and $x_2$ for the roots of both equations? How can I improve what I've written? What to do next?

Comment: It is very confusing! And plain wrong: you have $x_1+x_2=x_1+1+x_2+1$, which implies $0=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next
substitute $x_1+x_2=-p$ into $x_1+x_2+2=p^2$ to obtain $2-p=p^2$, which you can solve for $p$.

To find $q$, expand $(x_1+1)(x_2+1)=pq$ to get $x_1x_2+(x_1+x_2)+1=pq$, which is the same as $q-p+1=pq$.

And you should not use $x_1,x_2$ to mean two different things.

Comment: Wow, you are fast!! hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Another way :

Like [If $p, q$ and $r$ are distinct roots of $x^3-x^2+x-2=0$, find the value of $p^3+q^3+r^3$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486173/if-p-q-and-r-are-distinct-roots-of-x3-x2x-2-0-find-the-value-of-p3/3486207#3486207)

let $x_k+1=y_k; k=1,2$

$\implies x_k=y_k-1$

As $x_k$ is a root of $$x^2+px+q=0$$

$$(y_k-1)^2+p(y_k-1)+q=0$$

Comment: @Nikol, 'i' was capitalized by the editor.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure I understand. You use $x_k$ and $y_k$ for $4$ different values, right? What happens next?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can edit your coment and add more explanations.

Comment: @gixide, not for $4$ but $2$ different values. Just simplify the last line to form a quadratic equation in $y_k$

Comment: $x_k \rightarrow x_1,x_2$ and $y_k \rightarrow y_1,y_2$ $-$ 4 values.

Comment: $(y_k-1)^2+p(y_k-1)+q=0 \Leftrightarrow y_k^2-2y_k+1+py_k-p+q=0$. What next?

Comment: @gixide, $k=1\implies x_1\to y_1$ and $k=2\implies x_2\to y_2$

Comment: Yes, I got this. But after simplifying?

Comment: @gixide, We get the   quadratic equation whose roots are $y_1,y_2$  right?

Comment: May I ask how to find the restriction? I get $(p=1;q)$ for $\forall q$. What's the restriction on $q$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102561/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-gixide7609).

Comment: Okay. Let us continue there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried this:

Set the equations:

$-p = x_1 + x_2 (a),     x_1x_2 = q (b) $

$p^2 = x_1 +x_2 +2   (c),      (x_1 + 1)(x_2 + 1) = pq (d)$

So, let's substitute (a) in (c), then we will have:

$p^2 = -p + 2$

Solving it, we'll have:

$p=-2$

$p=1$

About $q$:

Let's expand the product of (d) and substitute (b) in it. Then, we'll have:

$q -p +1=pq$

Since we have the equation (d,b), we have to check for which values of $p$ it still makes sense. Therefore:

$(p,q)={(-2,-1),(1,-1)}$

Comment: "About q:" What if $p=1$?

Comment: I forgot to conclude, thanks

Comment: Doesn't $(p=1; q=-1)$ make sense?

Comment: Yes, I miss calculated. Again.... Thanks

Comment: How about $(p,q) = (1, -42)$?

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. What’s wrong? Assuming just some pairs as solution?

Comment: If $p=1$, is there any restriction on $q$?

Comment: @CatalinZara, may I ask how to find the restriction? I get $(p=1;q)$ for $\forall q$. What's the restriction on $q$?

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot answering that. Yes, there is no restriction for $q$ in this case. Because the equation that relates $p$ and $q$ can be rewritten as $ -(p-1)=q(p-1)$ and as we can see, when $p=1$, $q$ can be any number that you want, even complex since the equation will became $-(1-1)=q(1-1)$ which is $0=q0$.